# Compiler warning in static conditional

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, templates, compiler-warnings

I use a template parameter to determine if a certain behavior must be done or not. But this code generate a warning on VS2008 : `Warning    26  warning C4127: conditional expression is constant`

Here an exemple of the code :

```
template <class param, bool param2=true>
class superclass1
{
public:
  int foo()
  {
     if(param2)
        doSomthingMore();

     return 1;
   }
};
```

Is there a way to tranform the code to remove the warning and get the same features?

Comment: Yes, it's called "template meta programming".

Comment: By the way, the warning has nothing to do with the "default parameter".

Comment: Yeah you are right, I should find a better title for this question, do you have any idea @KerrekSB?

Comment: I used to get this message when doing the same thing, but do not anymore. It may be on VC++ 2010 that it no longer gives the warning. I prefer this over template specializations. You can also do similar things with template `int`s which you can't do with specializations.

Comment: Stupid question : are you compiling with the \w4 flag @JohnPS?

Comment: @Drahakar - I get the warnings with \w4 flag on your simple example in both VC++ 2008 and 2010. I have a bigger project using template `bool` and `int` in if-statements that does not issue warnings. I have to sleep on it to remember if I changed something to disable the warnings.

Comment: @Drahakar: Meh, I don't know... it doesn't really matter now I guess. Maybe "Compiler warning in static conditional" or so.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Sounds good to me, thank you.

Comment: It's a silly warning. Constant conditionals are _good_; the compiler can just optimise them out.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Is "silly warning" a technical term when it comes to MSVC? I've heard this several times now...

Comment: @KerrekSB: "silly" is an "alternative representation" keyword for the term "MSVC"

Comment: `naturedef silly MSVC;`?! I just ran into that warning and I _really_ would like to know whether the compiler _really_ optimizes the constant branch... Unfortunatelly there's a lot of inlining etc. around that statement so I have to hope that the abscence of any conditional jump several lines up and down means "optimized out"...[additionally it's a function so no partial specialization...] (Why the warning if it gets optimized anyway?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done via partial specialization. The crudest version looks like this:

```
template <typename, bool> class superclass1;

template <class param> class superclass1<param, true>
class superclass1
{
public:
  int foo()
  {
    doSomthingMore();
    return 1;
  }
};

template <class param> class superclass1<param, false>
class superclass1
{
public:
  int foo()
  {
    return 1;
  }
};
```

A more sophisticated approach might declare a member template function and only specialize *that*. Here's a solution with auxiliary tag classes:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool B> class Foo
{
  struct true_tag {};
  struct false_tag {};
  void f_impl(true_tag = true_tag()){}     // your code here...
  void f_impl(false_tag = false_tag()){}   // ... and here

public:
  void foo()
  {
    f(typename std::conditional<B, true_tag, false_tag>::type());
  }
};
```

Comment: I hoped this wasn't the only solution since this pattern exist at more than one place in the class.

Comment: @Drahakar: I added a more sophisticated, local version. TMP is a huge subject, and if you're only getting started, be assured that you're entering a world of pure magic. :-)

Comment: An other good question is : Should I correct this warning, or just pragma disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Or just enclose your sensitive code with `#pragma warning( disable : 4127 )` and `#pragma warning( default: 4127 )` to avoid writing the same logic twice (though it doesnt apply to the simple case described in the question).